# VSIX Extension for SSMS - Context menu for result grid

Tags: ssms, add-in, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I made an extension for SSMS (version 2016 and 17). I could insert items to object explorer's context menu. But cannot find any information about how can I access the context menu of result grid.

:[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: Hello, have you found a solution?

Comment: unfortunately not

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?